# Timeline Plot with Date Intervals and Caption Array

Tags: plotting, charts, education, intervals

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this example mentioned in the mathematica website below (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimelinePlot.html), except I'm trying to get the event dates and captions from given arrays.

[image]

```
// Given Date Interval Array
xDates = [
 {{1999, 03, 11}, {2000, 09, 11}},
 {{2011, 09, 11}, {2012, 05, 6}},
 {{2012, 06, 14}, {2014, 02, 12}},
 {{2014, 04, 14}, {2015, 09, 11}}
 ]

//Captions Array

xCaption = 
[
 {“Abc”},
 {“Def”},
 {“Ghi”},
 {“Jkl”}
]
```

and finally plotting the graph with

```
TimelinePlot[Labeled[Interval[xDates], xCaptions]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your `xDates` and `xCaptions` are not correctly formatted: you have to get rid of the outer square brackets:

```
xDates = {{{1999, 03, 11}, {2000, 09, 11}}, {{2011, 09, 11}, {2012, 05, 6}},
{{2012, 06, 14}, {2014, 02, 12}}, {{2014, 04, 14}, {2015, 09, 11}}};
xCaptions = Flatten@{{"Abc"}, {"Def"}, {"Ghi"}, {"Jkl"}};
```

Additionally, `Flatten` the original `xCaptions` so it's a list of strings, not a list of single-element lists.

Then, put it in a format that `TimelinePlot` will understand:

```
lab = Table[Labeled[Interval[xDates[[i]]], xCaptions[[i]]], {i, 1, Length@xDates}];
```

and finally

```
TimelinePlot[lab]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I was stuck for days :)